# Could not load the Tomcat server configuration

Tags: spring, tomcat, web, spring-tool-suite, catalina

I edited `catalina.properties` trying to change the port of the server, it didn't work and restored the original values and now I am getting the following error:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/VMware
>   vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.9-config. The configuration may
>   be corrupt or incomplete. Resource is out of sync with the file
>   system: '/Servers/VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition
>   v2.9-config/catalina.properties'.

This is the default server provided by Spring Tool Suite.

The solutions I found did not help me, like copying all the TOMCAT_DIR/conf files to my server location, which is in `workspace/Servers`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a Tomcat port, you need to edit server.xml, not catalina.properties  See: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/).

Try reinstall/unzip again, and start from scratch.  I often mess up servers, and can never work out what happened.  It is much faster in the long run to reinstall.

Also, before you do that, try F5 in your IDE, because 'out of sync with file system' usually means you need to press F5 (refresh).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, that my problem is the same, I had similar issue about ports conflict.
My solution was based on changing ports in **catalina.properties**. I deleted default **Pivotal tc Server**, than found in installation **catalina.properties** on the path

> sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE/tcServer/conf.

The last 4 lines in file are:

```
base.shutdown.port=-1
base.jmx.port=6969
bio.http.port=8080
bio.https.port=8443
```

Change ports as you like (to have unused ports).

Create a new server. select **Pivotal -> Pivotal tc Server**... **next**.
On the next page push radio button **Existing Instance** and select **tcServer**. **Finish**. 
Than try to start server to check, if ports are unused yet. If yes, the server should start.